# My code becoming horrible with Mongoose "Foreign Key"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise

I'm using Node.js 4.x and Mongoose 4.6.0 with MongoDB 3.2.

I have relationship on my models and when I want to create an object I have to create another one to link them. And I have to check before if the object doesn't exists then I create it and I use the created `_id` else I'll use the existing object `_id`

**E.g for Office Model**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create Office schema
var officeSchema = new Schema({
    name        : { type: String, required: true },
    address     : String,
    city        : String,
    zip_code    : String,
    geolocation : [ { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Geolocation' } ],
    company     : [ { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Company' } ]
});

var Office = mongoose.model('Office', officeSchema, 'Office');

module.exports = Office;
```

As you can see if I want to create an Office I have to create a Company and Geolocation object.

So I have a problem because my code becoming unreadable and very synchronous. I think there is a better solution to make my code cleaner. For example using Promise maybe ? But I don't know how can I do that in my case.

I'm open for all suggestions. Here is an example of my code.

```
app.post('/init/complete', function(req, res){

    var companyName   = toTitleCase(req.body.company);

    // Find or Create Company
    Company.findOne({'name': companyName}, function(err, company){

        if (err) throw err;

        // Check existing Company
        if( !company ){

            var newCompany = Company({
                name: companyName
            });

            // Save the Company
            newCompany.save(function(err, companyCreated) {
                if (err) throw err;

                findOrCreateOffice(companyCreated, req);
            });
        }else{
            findOrCreateOffice(company, req);
        }
    });
});

// Find or create office with the geolocation
function findOrCreateOffice(company, req){

    var officeName  = toTitleCase(req.body.office);
    var address     = req.body.address;
    var city        = req.body.city;
    var zipcode     = req.body.zipcode;
    var latitude    = req.body.latitude;
    var longitude   = req.body.longitude;

    Office.findOne({'name': officeName}, function(err, office){

        if (err) throw err;

        // Check existing Office
        if( !office ){

            // Create new Geolocation
            var newGeoloc = Geolocation({
                latitude: latitude,
                longitude: longitude
            });

            // Save the Geolocation
            newGeoloc.save(function(err) {
                if (err) throw err;

                // Create new Office
                var newOffice = Office({
                    name        : officeName,
                    address     : address,
                    city        : city,
                    zip_code    : zipcode,
                    geolocation : newGeoloc._id,
                    company     : company._id
                });

                // Save the Office
                newOffice.save(function(err, officeCreated) {
                    if (err) throw err;

                    updateUser(officeCreated, req)
                });
            });
        }else{
            updateUser(office, req)
        }
    });
}

// Update User informations
function updateUser(office, req){

    var phone     = req.body.phone;
    var job       = req.body.job;
    var notif     = req.body.notif;

    User.findOne({ 'email' : req.user.email }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) throw err;

        // Update User
        user.phone        = phone;
        user.type         = job;
        user.email_notif  = notif;
        user.account_init = true;
        user.office       = office._id;

        user.save(function(err){
            if(err) throw err;

            res.json('SUCCESS');
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: i agree man.....